# Google pubsub emulator constantly pushes the same messages?

Tags: kotlin, google-cloud-pubsub

I am building a testing library that abstracts away some 3rd party resources such as Google PubSub.

The issue is when I create a topic and a subscription, messages arrive constantly. Example output:

> ack_id: "projects/test-project-123/subscriptions/my-subscription:2"
> message {   data: "My message!-1"   message_id: "2"   publish_time {
> seconds: 1614597484   } }
>
> ack_id: "projects/test-project-123/subscriptions/my-subscription:4"
> message {   data: "My message!-1"   message_id: "2"   publish_time {
> seconds: 1614597484   } }

Curiously enough, publish time is the same.

The code that pulls the messages:

```
fun poll(size: Int, subscriptionId: String): List<String> {
    val subscriberStubSettings: SubscriberStubSettings = SubscriberStubSettings.newBuilder()
        .setTransportChannelProvider(channelProvider)
        .setCredentialsProvider(credentialsProvider)
        .build()
    GrpcSubscriberStub.create(subscriberStubSettings).use { subscriber ->
        val pullRequest: PullRequest = PullRequest.newBuilder()
            .setMaxMessages(size)
            .setSubscription(ProjectSubscriptionName.format(projectId, subscriptionId))
            .build()
        val pullResponse: PullResponse = subscriber.pullCallable().call(pullRequest)


        val acknowledgeRequest = AcknowledgeRequest.newBuilder()
            .setSubscription(ProjectSubscriptionName.format(projectId, subscriptionId))
            .addAllAckIds(
                pullResponse.receivedMessagesList
                    .stream()
                    .map { it.ackId }.toList()
            ).build()

        return pullResponse.receivedMessagesList
            .map { it.message.data.toStringUtf8() }
            .toList()
    }
}
```

I am trying to pull messages one by one from each subscription:

```
fun purge() {
    for (subscription in listSubscriptionIds()) {
        var messages = poll(MESSAGE_BATCH_SIZE, subscription)
        while (messages.isNotEmpty()) {
            messages = poll(MESSAGE_BATCH_SIZE, subscription)
        }
    }
}
```

Extra functions:

```
private val channelProvider: TransportChannelProvider
    get() {
        return FixedTransportChannelProvider
            .create(
                GrpcTransportChannel.create(channel())
            )
    }

private fun channel(): ManagedChannel {
    return if (channels.isEmpty()) {
        val endpoint = emulator.emulatorEndpoint
        val channel = ManagedChannelBuilder
            .forTarget(endpoint)
            .usePlaintext()
            .build()
        channels.add(channel)
        channel
    } else {
        channels.first()
    }
}

var emulator: PubSubEmulatorContainer = PubSubEmulatorContainer(
        DockerImageName.parse("gcr.io/google.com/cloudsdktool/cloud-sdk:latest")
    )
```

How can I overcome it? Is it a bug, or am I doing anything wrong?

Comment: Are you getting repeat messages immediately in every call through the loop or after some period of time? Where is the code where you ack the messages?

Comment: It repeats after a while, so I assume that messages don't get acknowledge and redelivered. I updated my code with a redelivery mechanism.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code should *acknowledge* that you have received (and, presumably, handled) each message:

> Once a message is sent to a subscriber, the subscriber should acknowledge the message. A message is considered outstanding once it has been sent out for delivery and before a subscriber acknowledges it. Pub/Sub will repeatedly attempt to deliver any message that has not been acknowledged. ([ref](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/subscriber#delivery))

Those repeated attempts are what you are seeing here, so it looks like that acknowledgement isn't happening. Try the [Acknowledge](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/reference/rpc/google.pubsub.v1#google.pubsub.v1.Subscriber) RPC call.

Comment: Do you know how to do with an emulator? I cannot find any example.

Comment: Your edited code creates an AcknowledgeRequest which is then not actually used anywhere. The [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/pull#synchronous_pull) has a Java example; the important line is the `subscriber.acknowledgeCallable().call(acknowledgeRequest);`.

Comment: Also note that you would normally acknowledge that you have handled each message _after you have handled it_, so depending on what the rest of your code looks like, that is probably later than in the call to `poll`. In this example, because you don't actually do anything with the message, immediately acknowledging them is fine.

Comment: Thx, you helped me a lot!